# Refreshing NSTreeController from CoreData

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I am developing a cocoa app which has NSOutlineView which is binded to NSTreeController with CoreData integration.

For some purposes, I am deleting some of the nodes in NSTreeController by

```
MyTreeController.removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndexPath(someIndexPath)
```

But than, I need to reload the NSTreeController back from CoreData by using the current binding. However, I couldn't find a solution because NSTreeController has no reload data function.

Any help or a workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: The reload data function is called `fetch:`.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for replying. I tried fetch as MyTreeontroller.fetch(nil) after using MyTreeController.removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndexPath(someIndexPath) commad but the removed items were not received back from the context.

Comment: Are the objects removed from the context?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `-removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndexPath` against a `NSTreeController` that is associated with Core Data will remove the object from Core Data.

Calling `-fetch:` afterwards is going to cause the data to return, it has been deleted.